# Remove split screen on top editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently having a split screen on top of my editor which I am unable to remove. Have tried everything, from restarting PC, setting editor layout and restarting VS Code. I never seen it before and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What "split screen"? Do you mean the [sticky scroll](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_sticky-scroll)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Preferences
And delect "Sticky Scroll: Enabled" [image]

Answer (score 0):

At the top menu: View > Appearance > Sticky Scroll